# Nuxt 3 Authentication with Laravel 9 and Sanctum

Tags: authentication, oauth, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, laravel-sanctum

I'm using nuxt 3 for a project and can't find an easy way to do authentication with Laravel and Sanctum.

The @nuxtjs/axios module is only compatible for nuxt 2 and the package a developer provided for nuxt 3 (@nuxtjs-alt/auth)  doesn't provide much documentation. I tried to implement it but nuxtApp().$auth always returns undefined.

How can I authenticate my user in the Login screen and then have an auth middleware to secure my routes? I reiterate the use of NUXT3

Comment: You can use cookies to store auth token, get it at a server plugin , store it at a central state so that you can access it everywhere both in ssr and front end.After that you want to create a middleware that checks whether the token is present in the central store and of course deny or allow the requested route.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great article for how to setup authentication with Laravel Sanctum and Nuxt 3 with SSR here:

https://manchenkoff.medium.com/laravel-10-and-nuxt-3-setup-ssr-with-authentication-from-scratch-497ab1a3fc56

The author later released his solution as an npm package:

https://github.com/manchenkoff/nuxt-auth-sanctum

Answer (score 0):

Just found this Nuxt 3 sanctum package on GitHub:

https://github.com/dystcz/nuxt-sanctum-auth

Seems like a solution until the official auth module is published for nuxt3.

Comment: I have found  this [https://github.com/amrnn90/breeze-nuxt], will create time to test both implementation and advice

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).